# How to set videoView in Dialog android

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

How to set videoView in Dialog with fragment.

and I try is not work ( no show video )

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    final VideoView video_player_view = (VideoView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.videos);
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((HomeActivity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fong, null);

    dialog.setView(dialogLayout);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.show();

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://file2.video9.in/english/movie/2014/x-men-_days_of_future_past/X-Men-%20Days%20of%20Future%20Past%20Trailer%20-%20[Webmusic.IN].3gp");
    video_player_view.setVideoURI(uri);
    video_player_view.start();
```

and fragment_fong.xml (videoView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/videos" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How to set it, thanks for you help

Comment: Change : final VideoView video_player_view = (VideoView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.videos); to 
final VideoView video_player_view = (VideoView)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.videos);

Comment: @akhilesh0707 it's still error

Comment: does videoView show, but video doesn't play?

Comment: @UsmanRana Video Not show...

Comment: can you send screenshot? and give it a try by setting fix width and height of the view , instead of wrap_content . ivideoView shows or not in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video is not playing

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = ((HomeActivity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fong, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.setView(dialogLayout);
        dialog.show();
       // dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        final VideoView video_player_view = (VideoView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.videos);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://file2.video9.in/english/movie/2014/x-men-_days_of_future_past/X-Men-%20Days%20of%20Future%20Past%20Trailer%20-%20[Webmusic.IN].3gp");
        video_player_view.setVideoURI(uri);
        video_player_view.start();
```

Comment: I have some problem , now video is show and playing but video is change color like a background dialog (solid color). How to fix it